# How to vertically align XAML UWP checkbox

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to vertically align a checkbox. The actual box appears at the top. I want it to appear in the middle.

This is the XAML:

```
  <CheckBox FontSize="100" Content="Test" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I have seen similar questions on SO, but the answer was to use VerticalContentAlignment. This does not work. Some answers have suggested using negative padding or margins, which does not scale. So please don't mark as duplicate, this has not really been answered. Or perhaps it was answered for WPF but not for UWP.

I am aware that you can change the style of the control, but that is a lot of work for something that should just work out of the box.

I am using VS 2019 16.6.2 with UWP v6.2.10

### Update

This is what I would like my CheckBox to look.

[image: vertically aligned checkbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to vertically align XAML UWP checkbox

For the requirement, the better way is modify the checkbox's default layout. The default layout is `Column`, we need to change it to `Row`. And I will share the a part of style and you could use it directly.

```
<Grid
    x:Name="RootGrid"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
    >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid
        Height="32"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        >
        <Rectangle
            x:Name="NormalRectangle"
            Width="20"
            Height="20"
            Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillUnchecked}"
            Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckBackgroundStrokeUnchecked}"
            StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}"
            UseLayoutRounding="False"
            />
        <FontIcon
            x:Name="CheckGlyph"
            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
            FontSize="20"
            Foreground="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUnchecked}"
            Glyph="&#xE001;"
            Opacity="0"
            />
    </Grid>
    <ContentPresenter
        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        />
```

For the complete style please refer this [link](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GetFavTest/blob/master/GetFavTest/MainPage.xaml#L12).

**Update**
If do not want to edit the default style, we could make custom checkbox, and edit the layout in  `OnApplyTemplate` method.

```
public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var normalRectangle = GetTemplateChild("NormalRectangle") as Rectangle;
        var rootGrid = normalRectangle.Parent as Grid;
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(rootGrid, 2);
        rootGrid.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        var contentPresenter = GetTemplateChild("ContentPresenter") as ContentPresenter;
        Grid.SetColumn(contentPresenter, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(contentPresenter, 2);
        contentPresenter.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:CustomCheckBox FontSize="100" Content="Test"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

**Update 1**

use the following to replace `OnApplyTemplate` content.

```
var normalRectangle = GetTemplateChild("NormalRectangle") as Rectangle;
var rootGrid = normalRectangle.Parent as Grid;
Grid.SetColumnSpan(rootGrid, 2);
rootGrid.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left
rootGrid.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: If MS changes the appearance of the checkbox in a future release, my checkbox will look different from the others. I don't want to create a new type of checkbox, I just want to be able to change the alignment in one checkbox. I don't want change anything else.

Comment: You could give style x:key, and use it for specific checkbox, and it will be effect with 
 future release. And it looks only way could edit the default style.

Comment: Can MSFT not fix this so that VerticalContentAlignment property works? Changing a style is a lot of work for something that should be just a simple property change...

Comment: There is other way could edit the default layout, I will post above.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I've added CustomCheckBox public class. XAML not happy with <local:CheckBox, VS suggests I use xmlns:local="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls" (currently local is using my app namespace). That doesn't work either.

Comment: I have make code sample for this thread, please check [this](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GetFavTest).

Comment: @under, Sorry for the mistake, it is `<local:CustomCheckBox/>`

Comment: That did something, but the box is now in the middle above the text. Not in the vertical middle on the left. Perhaps I wasn't clear, I just want a "normal" checkbox that is on the left and with text on the right and is all aligned as per normal. I'll add a picture to the question

Comment: Ok, please post your screenshot in the case update.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! Thanks for the help. I think this should be the default behavior of the checkBox, maybe MSFT fixes it one day?